# Input field hidden by title in selenium

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on an automated selenium test which has a header with a fixed position.

```
    div#floatingDiv {
        position: fixed;
        background-color: #000000;
        color:white;            
    }
```

This floating header is getting in the way when try to automate selenium tests using the  Firefox web driver.

What appears to be happening is that when selenium clicks an element that is currently off the screen the Firefox web driver scrolls the page such that the button it is accessing is at the top of the page and then clicks the element. However since the header has a fixed position the element become hidden behind the header and the test fails.

Is there a way to directly control the scroll bar in selenium?

Having done some more experiments with this issue I noticed that this issue only happens when accessing buttons that are off the bottom of the page but not with input fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following untested Java code and you need some tweaks for where and how much to scroll

```
WebElement input = (Locatable) driver.findElement(By.xpath("some path to your input"));
int y = (Locatable)input .getCoordinates().getLocationOnScreen().getY();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+y+");");
input.click();
```

Comment: getLocationOnScreen() return's the location of the element with respect the screen. In my code it is returning 0,0 because the Firefox web driver is forcing the element to be scrolled to the top of the screen as soon as it is accessed.

Comment: @EsotericNonsense: Then you scroll it down again (without accessing the element) and click?

Comment: I got the window.scrollBy(x,y) method to work for me at least once but it's behaving weird. I the method doesn't seam to work when the page is scrolled to the middle of the page when it's called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the scrollTo method rather than the scroll by menthod.

```
public void scrollToElement(By by) {
    Locatable element = (Locatable) selenium.findElement(by);
    Point p= element.getCoordinates().getLocationOnScreen();
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) selenium;  
    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + p.getX() + "," + (p.getY()+150) + ");");
}
```